Command not found: {"SHELL"=>"bash"}
Trying to install specific version of K6 using brew and got error which I'm not sure how to solve it. Tried reinstall brew, using zsh as bash and still the same error.
Steps I used to install it:

brew tap-new $USER/local-k6
brew extract --version=0.52.0 k6 $USER/local-k6
brew install k6@0.52.0

Error I got:
brew: command not found: {"SHELL"=>"bash"}
Error: Failure while executing; `\{\"SHELL\"=\>\"bash\"\} /usr/local/Cellar/k6@0.52.0/0.52.0/bin/k6 completion bash` exited with 127. Here's the output:

brew version: Homebrew 4.3.20-77-g0fb4d51
I tried above same steps but with go1.22.6 just to make sure I can install different packages and it worked, but not with k6.


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

If someone who faces the same issues as I'm I finally found way around it:

brew search --closed --pull-request k6@0.48.0
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/4e1963117706a17f59efc3a56edb13044a19dbda/Formula/k6.rb
brew install ./k6.rb

this is source where I got those steps:https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/155
